# How to prevent StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, exception, chess

I am making a chess program for a long time. I have made a class called Checkmate to detect for Checks, Illegal moves, Checkmate and Stalemate. As of now I have just implemented Checks and Illegal moves. But whenever I run the program, it causes a StackOverflowError.

```
/**
 * <code>String player</code> contains the constant of the currently playing player.
 * This method will first find out the position of the opponent's King and store it in <code>Point opponentKing</code>.
 * After that, it will find all the currently playing player's pieces. It will find the possible moves of each of the piece.
 * If the <code>opponentKing</code> is found within the possible moves of any piece, it will return "true, else it will return "false".
 * @return "true" if it is check. "false" if it is not a check.
 */
public boolean getIsCheck(String[][] board) {
    boolean isCheck = false;
    Point opponentKing = new Point(0,0);
    outer: for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if(!board[i][j].substring(1).equals(player) && board[i][j].substring(0,1).equals(Board.KING)) {
                opponentKing = new Point(i, j);
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
    List<Point> friendlyPieces = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            if (board[i][j].substring(1).equals(player)
                    && !board[i][j].equals(Board.EMPTY))
                friendlyPieces.add(new Point(i, j));

    outer: for(Point p : friendlyPieces) {
        List<Point> availableMoves = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (board[p.x][p.y].substring(0,1)){
            case Board.PAWN: availableMoves = new Pawn(player).getCheckMoves(p); break;
            case Board.ROOK: availableMoves = new Rook(player).getAvailableMoves(p); break;
            case Board.KNIGHT: availableMoves = new Knight(player).getAvailableMoves(p); break;
            case Board.BISHOP: availableMoves = new Bishop(player).getAvailableMoves(p); break;
            case Board.KING: availableMoves = new King(player).getAvailableMoves(p); break;
            case Board.QUEEN: availableMoves = new Queen(player).getAvailableMoves(p); break;
        }
        for (Point point: availableMoves) {
            if(point.equals(opponentKing)) {
                isCheck = true;
                break outer;
            }
        }
    }
    return isCheck;
}
```

That is the code for finding whether the current position of the pieces of the board is in a state of a check for the king.

```
public boolean getIsIllegal(Point start, Point end, Pieces piece){
    String[][] board = Board.board;
    board[start.x][start.y] = Board.EMPTY;
    board[end.x][end.y] = piece.getPiece() + piece.getPlayer();
    return getIsCheck(board);
}
```

This is the getIsIllegal() in the same class Checkmate.

Whenever i choose the pawn from the board. It gives me the following error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Pieces.Pawn.getCheckMoves(Pawn.java:56)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsCheck(Checkmate.java:60)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsIllegal(Checkmate.java:81)
    at Pieces.Knight.getAvailableMoves(Knight.java:30)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsCheck(Checkmate.java:62)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsIllegal(Checkmate.java:81)
    at Pieces.Knight.getAvailableMoves(Knight.java:34)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsCheck(Checkmate.java:62)
    at Win.Checkmate.getIsIllegal(Checkmate.java:81)
```

And so on.

```
if (x<7 && y<6 && isEmpty(x + 1, y + 2) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x + 1, y + 2));
    if (x>0 && y<6 && isEmpty(x - 1, y + 2) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x - 1, y + 2));
    if (x<6 && y>0 && isEmpty(x + 2, y - 1) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x + 2, y - 1));
    if (x<6 && y<7 && isEmpty(x + 2, y + 1) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x + 2, y + 1));
    if (x<7 && y>1 && isEmpty(x + 1, y - 2) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x + 1, y - 2));
    if (x>0 && y>1 && isEmpty(x - 1, y - 2) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x - 1, y - 2));
    if (x>1 && y>0 && isEmpty(x - 2, y - 1) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x - 2, y - 1));
    if (x>1 && y<7 && isEmpty(x - 2, y + 1) && !check.getIsIllegal(point, new Point(x, y), this)) availableMoves.add(new Point(x - 2, y + 1));
```

The above code are the lines I have written to get the available moves for the Knight on the current board. This is where the constant looping between the getIsCheck() and getIsIllegal() is. Please refer to the Exception for further clarification.

Comment: What is the code for `getAvailableMoves()`; Are you calling additional methods there? If I'm understanding this correctly, your stack is: `getIsIllegal()` --> `getIsCheck()` --> `getCheckMoves()/getAvailableMoves()`?

Comment: Your `isCheck` method is very expensive. I'd suggest instead storing the Kings position at the beginning, and changing it as it moves.

Comment: I have written a part of the code in getAvailableMoves() in my question. The last snippet of code(containing 8 ifs) is the code for Knight.getAvailableMoves(). Yes, in this method, im calling getIsIllegal(). If suppose this logic/approch is wrong, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

A piece checks the king although the move of the piece is not legal! E.g: White Kc2, Rb2 - Black Kh2, Ba3:

[image]

After the move Kc2-c1 the Rb2 gives check, although the Rb2 can't move.

Change your defintion of available and illegal move: a available move can be illegal. So getAvailableMoves() doesn't call getIsIllegal(). So Rb2-h2 is a available move and the method isCheck() works.

Now, to get the legal moves, you have to code like this:

```
...
Pieces piece;
switch (board[p.x][p.y].substring(0,1)){
    case Board.PAWN: piece = new Pawn(player); break;
    case Board.ROOK: piece = new Rook(player); break;
    case Board.KNIGHT: piece = new Knight(player); break;
    case Board.BISHOP: piece = new Bishop(player); break;
    case Board.KING: piece = new King(player); break;
    case Board.QUEEN: piece = new Queen(player); break;
} 

List<Point> availableMoves = piece.getAvailableMoves(p);
List<Point> legalMoves = new ArrayList<>();

for (Point point : availableMoves ) {
    if (!getIsIllegal(p, point, piece))
        legalMoves.add(point);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to tell you that this will also result in a StackOverflowError. Whenever I check for an illegal move using getIsIllegal(), I make a copy of the original board and assume that the player wants to play a certain move and then check whether is the board is at check assuming the player plays that move using getIsCheck(). Hence, the getIsIllegal() and getIsCheck() will keep calling each other. I wanted to delete this question as I found out the answer myself. Anyway, thanks for giving me an idea, I will implement it in another place.